# What does ‘type’ signify in a transaction?

Tags: transactions

I am looking at a block of transactions. Most of them have type set to 0x2. Some of them however have type set to 0x0. I can't find where specifically Ethereum describes what the 'type' field means in a transaction, and same is true for a few of the other fields.

Not sure if it is the same as 'TransactionType' described here: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2718

Either way, this EIP seems to just describe allowable values, but does not say what they currently represent.

In this official doc (https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/transactions/), it just refers to the EIP above, but again doesn't say anything about the meaning of the value 0x0 or 0x2.

Answer (score 1):

Transaction type 0x2 was introduced in [EIP 1559](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1559).

Transaction type 0x1 was introduced in [EIP 2718](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2718), but the same functionality is also supported by type 0x2 there's a proposal to remove type 0x1 [EIP 3709](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3709).

Comment: OK it makes sense now… I’m thinking that 0x0 is legacy transactions, 0x2 is the new London hard fork where users pay the base fee and can pay miner tips for priority.  Probably most clients/wallets are updated so most transactions are 0x2.